# Manage uploaded image in nest js

Tags: node.js, nestjs, multer

I use multer to manage uploaded file:

```
@Post('upload') @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor("images", 10, {
  dest: "./uploads",
}))
uploadMultiple(@UploadedFiles() files) {
  console.log(files, 'test');
}
```

I try to add a file extension to my uploaded files as:

```
@Post('upload') @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor("images", 10, {
  dest: "./uploads",
   filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '.jpg') //Appending .jpg
  }
}))
```

But when I do this I get an error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '{ dest: string; filename: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MulterOptions'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'filename' does not exist in type 'MulterOptions'
```

How to specify file extension to my uploaded files?

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload says the interceptor accepts options as defined at https://github.com/expressjs/multer#multeropts which indeed doesn't have a `filename` property. That property is for a `DiskStorage`, which presumably you could pass as `storage`: https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it dynamically using the `extname` import from `path` using the `diskStorage` to get your filename extension.

```js
import { extname } from 'path';
import { diskStorage } from 'multer';

export const exampleDiskStorage = diskStorage({
  destination: './public/img/users',
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    return cb(null, `${Date.now()}${extname(file.originalname)}`);
  }
});
```

In your module, you only need to import the `diskStorage` to `MulterModule.register`

```js
import { MulterModule } from '@nestjs/platform-express';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MulterModule.register({
      storage: exampleDiskStorage,
    }),
  ],
});
```